# Want to update foreign key table at same time when primary key update in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario with a table `RegisteredUsers` and a primary key on `userid`.

Here is code:

```
create table RegisteredUsers
(
    userId INT not null IDENTITY(1,1), 
    userName varchar(255) not null,
    userpassword varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (userId)
);
```

A second table `Answers` has a foreign key reference to `RegisteredUsers`:

```
create table answers (
   surveyid int not null    
   foreign key (userId) references RegisteredUsers (userId)
);
```

Whenever I insert a row into the first table, I want to also insert a row into table `Answers`. When I insert value now, it only inserts into the first table. What do I need to do?

I am using SQL Server 2008. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for an insert trigger. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: The reason why we use foreign key is to allow insert in the table that has value exists in primary key, not to insert foreign key when you insert a primary key. if the not part is what you need then you should have in the same table.

Comment: So when someone registers, you want to create a record on the answers table? Sounds like a job for application code or as @asawyer said, an insert trigger... What have you tried??

Comment: Hard to know exactly what the question is. But if you need to get the autoincrementing primary key from the most recently inserted user, use SCOPE_IDENTITY.

Comment: If you want to automatically insert a row into `Answers` - how is the `SurveyId` going to be determined?? It's not an `IDENTITY` column, so you must provide a valid, unique value for each row you're inserting...

Comment: sounds like you have redundant information in the second table??  you should just have the `surveyid` in the `RegisteredUsers` Table.  the answers table should have a Primary Key of `surveyid` and should be a foreign key of the `RegisteredUsers` table.

Comment: Actually this question asked by me before 4 years ago when I was creating my university project, which clone of surveymokey.com. So at that time I have no idea how we retrieve identity and insert sub items on the base of parent id. So accidentally I view my profile today and I think I need to put a comment for no reason. :P